# Roboto Condensed and PDF device

Tags: r, fonts

I have been trying without success to use the pdf device (i.e., `pdf()`) in R to export a plot where I am using the `hrbrthemes` package. I know I can use `cairo_pdf` without problems but I am interested in some of the features supported by pdf such as `colormodel` and `paper`. I have tried removing and reinstalling extrafont and also removing and reintalling Roboto Condensed without success. I am attempting this in a Windows system.

```
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

fonts()
fonts()[grep("Roboto", fonts())]
#[1] "Roboto"

import_roboto_condensed()
fonts()[grep("Roboto", fonts())]
# [1] "Roboto"           "Roboto Condensed"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  labs(
    x = "Miles per gallon",
    y = "Horsepower",
    title = "Using so much gas",
    subtitle = "A bunch of cars"
  )

ggsave("mypdf.pdf")
# This create a pdf with no text and also gives the following error:
# Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
#   invalid font type

ggsave("mypdf_cairo.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
# This works but cairo does not seem to support some features like colormodel (i.e., cmyk) and paper.

loadfonts()
# More than one version of regular/bold/italic found for Roboto Condensed. Skipping setup for this font.
```